# Is it possible to build the same GridBagLayout interface but without using extra JPanel as a container?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using `GridBagLayout` to design the interface. The interface has one `JTabbedPane` set at north and fill both directions as I resize, and just below the `JTabbedPane` there are two `JButton`s.

What I want to achieve is putting these two buttons at **east** with using **only** `GridBagLayout` capabilities (without introducing an extra `JPanel`), but I failed to do so.

|-[tab]--------------------------|
|---------------------------------|
|---------------------------------|
|---------------------------------|
|---------------------------------|
|-------------[button][button]|

When I set the layout constraint for both buttons to WEST (not EAST). Both go west correctly!

`c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;`

But when I set the layout constraint for both buttons to east

`c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;`

One of them go to east and the other go to west!

To solve this issue I added a `JPanel` which hold both buttons and added this `JPanel` into the interface, and set its layout constraint to `c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;`. It works well.

**But is it possible to build the same `GridBagLayout` interface without using an extra `JPanel` as a container?**

The following two classes are in **SSCCE** format; the first one show the problem *`GridBagTest`*, and the other show the solution *`GridBagTest_solved`* that make use of extra `JPanel`

**Problem class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GridBagTest extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    JPanel panel_tab;

    JButton btn_previous;
    JButton btn_next;

    private void create_and_layout() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 150);
            }
        };

        panel_tab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", panel_tab);

        btn_previous = new JButton("previous");
        btn_next = new JButton("  next  ");

        GridBagConstraints c;

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        this.add(tabbedPane, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.insets = new Insets(2, 0, 2, 2);
        this.add(btn_previous, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.insets = new Insets(2, 0, 2, 2);
        this.add(btn_next, c);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        create_and_layout();
        frame = new JFrame("GridBagTest");
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new GridBagTest()::initGUI);
    }
}
```

**Solution class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GridBagTest_solved extends JPanel {

    JFrame frame;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    JPanel panel_tab;
    JPanel panel_buttons;

    JButton btn_previous;
    JButton btn_next;

    private void create_and_layout() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 150);
            }
        };

        panel_tab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", panel_tab);

        panel_buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        btn_previous = new JButton("previous");
        btn_next = new JButton("  next  ");

        GridBagConstraints c;
        // Adding buttons to panel_buttons
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(2, 0, 2, 2);
        panel_buttons.add(btn_previous, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(2, 0, 2, 2);
        panel_buttons.add(btn_next, c);

        // Adding tabbedPane & panel_buttons to this (GridBagTest_solved)
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        this.add(tabbedPane, c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        this.add(panel_buttons, c);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        create_and_layout();
        frame = new JFrame("GridBagTest_solved");
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new GridBagTest_solved()::initGUI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the three components - the JTabbedPane and two JButtons, you should consider using a simpler layout than GridBag. Just use a BorderLayout for the main panel, placing the JTabbedPane in CENTER, and a JPanel in SOUTH that has a FlowLayout with alignment of TRAILING, then just add the two buttons to that JPanel.

Comment: The code is just simplified to adhere to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - And as I solved my problem, I just want to know if there is a solution that uses only `GridBagLayout` capabilities.